# How to fix the sound in Safari

Tags: html, css, web, safari

I have a simple web page the sounds it totally works fine in Chrome and Mozilla but when it comes to Safari, it is not working.
Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

With `Safari 11` they've updated the `autoplay` policies. This means `mouseover` events will no longer be able to trigger audio sounds on your initial page. It will work once the user takes an action. You can actually see this on your page. Just click on the page and then hover over your content and it will work.

Learn more about it here: https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

The recommended workaround is it to use a UI element, which the user needs to confirm if he is using safari.

In code this would look like this:

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just wanted to ask, even when I am clicking on the page and then hovering it is not making any sound. Is there anything else I need to do? Or should I add any codes? Thanks a lot.